# How does typecasting a char to a structure work

Tags: c, casting

I have

```
 evnt_buff =  sSpiInformation.pRxPacket;
 data_to_recv = 0;
 hci_hdr = (hci_hdr_t *)(evnt_buff + sizeof(btspi_hdr));
```

My evnt_buff is 2. Now when I typecast the above data the hci_hdr

```
typedef struct _hci_hdr_t
{
    unsigned char ucType;
    unsigned char ucOpcode;
    unsigned char pad[3];
} hci_hdr_t;
```

`hci_hdr->ucType` has a value of 0. Is this the expected behaviour?

```
typedef struct _btspi_hdr
{
    unsigned char   cmd;
    unsigned short  length;
    unsigned char   pad[2];
}btspi_hdr;
```

My `unsigned char *evnt_buff`; is as defined . And why exacty is the `sizeof()` being added here?

The above piece of code gets called from another function. The other function initializes `sSpiInformation.pRxPacket` to point to a buffer whose first element is 2. This means that when

```
 evnt_buff =  sSpiInformation.pRxPacket;
```

is executed it becomes equal to 2.

Another thing. Since I am porting the code from one compiler to another , in the first compiler `#pragma pack(1)` is used to declare all the structures. But since in my compiler I dont know the equivalent of that I simply removed that statement and initialized the structure without any packing. Could this be the issue?

Comment: There isn't enough information in the question, I think, but I certainly see nothing to rule out the possibility that `ucType` is zero.  You'd need to explain what you mean by 'my `evnt_buf` is 2'. You'd need to show what's in `evnt_buff` (or, equivalently, `sSpiInformation.pRxPacket`); you need to worry about padding in `btspi_hdr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
hci_hdr = (hci_hdr_t *)(evnt_buff + sizeof(btspi_hdr));
```

implies that the memory pointed to by `evnt_buff` consists of

1. an instance of `btspi_hdr`
2. an instance of `hci_hdr_t`

So what the above line does is assigning to `hci_hdr` the address of that part of the memory pointed to by `evnt_buff` which represents the `hci_hdr_t` by adding the size of a `btspi_hdr` to `evnt_buff`.

From this I conclude `hci_hdr` is declared as `hci_hdr_t *`.

Comment: evnt_buff is a character pointer. It holds 2. So when I typecast it and add the size should I not get a 2 hci_hdr->uctype

Comment: `even_buff` holds an address which points to a `btspi_hdr`. Adding to `even_buff` the size of `btspi_hdr` the result of this additions points to something different than `even_buff`, it points right **after** the `btspi_hdr` namely to a `hci_hdr_t`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you mean or try to achieve You say that `evnt_buff` is a pointer to a character array where the first element is 2. If so, how does `evnt_buff + sizeof(btspi_hdr)` make any sense whatsoever?

Anyway, the bug is post likely related to struct padding. Every compiler has an option to turn off padding, if not `#pragma pack` then something else. Check the compiler documentation.

When you have questionable code like this, which relies on struct alignment, you should also add static compile-time checks to verify that no padding is enabled. One way to do so is to define a macro which yields a compiler error if the passed parameter is incorrect. For example:

`#define static_assert (expr) {typedef char COMP_TIME_ASSERT[(expr) ? 1 : 0];}`

(if you have a C11 compiler, a better static_assert is available by the compiler)

Then for every struct, type something like this:

```
static_assert (sizeof(btspi_hdr) == sizeof(cmd) +
                                    sizeof(length) +
                                    sizeof(pad) );
```